Movie with couple that have an open marriage whether the husband likes it or not
In the mid 1990s I saw a movie I believe takes place in Europe and may have been European made. Of course the movie could be significantly older than that. It was in color and in English, but it could have been dubbed into English.
The first scene I remember is the husband driving a car and the wife is asleep next to him. A very good looking woman is driving in the lane next to him. They flirt with each other big time like the scene with Christie Brinkley in the movie National Lampoon's Vacation.
The husband and wife stop somewhere to eat. The woman from the road is there and the husband ends up having sex with her in the bathroom. Afterwards she asks "Your wife is so lovely. Why are you unfaithful to her?" The husband looks unhappy and says "because my wife is unfaithful to me."
Later it is revealed that the wife has insisted on an arrangement where she spends four nights a week with her husband and three nights a week with her boyfriend. The split may have been 3/4. Further into the movie I believe she wants to completely leave her husband for the boyfriend. That is all I remember about the movie. Sound familiar to anyone?

Thank you for the suggestion, but I have seen Into the Night and it is definitely not the movie I'm looking for.

yes, I remember I watched this film, but don't remember its name

@Alex  Even though you don't remember the title either, do you remember any of the actors who were in the movie? If not do you remember how it ends? I don't.

if I could get names of actors, it would be easy to find movie name. All I remember that guy was tall, probably blond. Also that boyfriend of the wife was actually kind of sadist. He tortured her and after meeting with his she returned home, her body was in bruises and husband began to worry about her and one night he stalked to this man house and saved his wife from death and they left together.

Nitpick, but a marriage is not open when one partner doesn't agree. Then it's still just cheating when the other has sex with third parties.

I eventually found the title of this movie. It is Husbands and Lovers (1991).

A scriptwriter working in Rome becomes distraught over his beauteous
wife and the "arrangement" they have when she discovers S&M with her
longtime pianist lover.


Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer.
